# Localstorage .key() function returns same key for all values. How to solve it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

**I am trying to retreive key of a value which is in the browser local storage**

But it returns same key for values which are stored in local storage but when i try to get value from key it give correct value.

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPWKQ.png)

**I am trying to remove active element from html as well as its data which is stored in localstorage**

```
function removefrom() {
   const element = document.activeElement;
   const key = localStorage.key(element.value);
   localStorage.removeItem(key);
   element.remove();
```

}

1. first i will get active selected element
2. i will pass active element's value from `element.value` (in line 2)
3. then i want to get key where the that value is in localstorage and then i will find key from passed value
4. in line 4, i will remove item from local storage from key
5. i will remove element from the dom

Comment: when in doubt, read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like this to fetch the values of keys stored in your local storage

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
}
```

For more you can refer this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key

Comment: or simply `Object.keys(localStorage)`

Comment: Yes, we can do this too

Comment: Yes but, i want specifically from that way. localstorage.key(n) returns same value for all data which i dont want. Why is that happening. Can anyone explain?